# How to configure Path in Websphere

Tags: java, url, path, websphere, websphere-8

I have two variables configured this way(Java code)

```
import java.net.URL;

@Resource(type = java.net.URL.class, name = "ref-url/S596-FGOEntrada", lookup = "url/S596-FGOEntrada")
private URL localEntrada;

@Resource(type = java.net.URL.class, name = "ref-url/S596-FGOSaida", lookup = "url/S596-FGOSaida")
private URL localSaida;
```

Can someone tell me how to set it up in the websphere 8.5?

[config was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uur1j.png)

[config url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rutZe.png)

```
0000003c BusinessExcep E   CNTR0019E: EJB emitiu uma exceção (não-declarada) inesperada durante a chamada do método "executarBatch". Dados da exceção:javax.ejb.EJBException: Injection failure; nested exception is: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: S2WKSF1795Node01Cell/nodes/S2WKSF1795Node01/servers/server1, name: url/S596-FGOSaida: First component in name S596-FGOSaida not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:475)

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: S2WKSF1795Node01Cell/nodes/S2WKSF1795Node01/servers/server1, name: url/S596-FGOSaida: First component in name S596-FGOSaida not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
```

Edit: this Path is to deposit files generated by the java code and to read files

Comment: By quick look, it looks ok. Did you save changes and restart the server?

Comment: Yes, several times